# Call Ajax function after 5 seconds

Tags: ajax

I am using Ajax to populate a div from a div on another page which is working fine. However, I would like to call the Ajax after 5 seconds, is this possible?

```
$.ajax({
url: '../../status/index.php',
success: function(data) {
data=$(data).find('div#status');
$('#serviceStatus').html(data);
}
});
```

Comment: so use setTimeout

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout